# How can I monitor users logging into subversion?

Tags: svn, collabnet

I was wondering if there was anyway in which I could obtain usage stats for collabnet subversion? I specifically want to know what users are connecting to the subversion server and how often?

I've looked around and there only seem to be tools that monitor user commits. Not everyone will have write access in subversion so that isn't really appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Users do not really "log in" to Subversion in the sense that they establish a persistent connection & conduct all activity through it. A connection is established, if credentials are required to perform the activity they are requested & exchanged, the transaction occurs, and the user disconnects.

Many repositories are set up such that read-only activities allow anonymous access, in which case you can't track what you're asking for here.

In the case of serving via Apache, this can mean that a single checkout may appear to be *hundreds* of "logins" because each item appears as a separate entry in the httpd log. However, with a semi-intelligent HTTPD log parser, you can probably glean the information from those logs.

Subversion itself doesn't log such activity because simply looking at the repository or checking out from it doesn't change the state.

Comment: alroc,

Thanks for your reply!

I just need to know what users are using subversion and I've looked through a http apache access log and I can see usernames in there - but as you mentioned, one user crops up hundreds of times!!

What's the best apache log analyser out there in order for me to sieve out the various users using subversion? I'm currently looking into using awstats?

Regards,